# Atmospheric correction in ENVI, export to ERDAS

Tags: envi, erdas-imagine, atmospheric-correction, minimum-noise-transformation

I am working on a project using Hyperspectral imagery and have ERDAS Imagine on my home PC and have access to ENVI on another PC at University. Is it possible, for example, to perform the atmospheric correction in ENVI, then import it into ERDAS, or vice versa, and perform Principal Component Analysis, Minimum Noise Transformation (MNF), supervised classification etc?

The file is a .l1r file from EO-1 Hyperion downloaded from GloVis.

I read here ([Imagine files between ERDAS and ENVI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91021/imagine-files-between-erdas-and-envi)) that you can export the file as a .bil and then import into ERDAS, so I presume it is possible?

I don’t have ENVI on this PC to double check at the moment.