# Opening rrd file in ENVI 5.3

Tags: envi, extensions, aster, files, rrd

I have three files with RRD extension, which are data files for ASTER and I do not know how to open them in ENVI 5.3?

Comment: Are they in imagine file that came from ERDAS ?

Comment: Kind of old but this might help you out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91021/imagine-files-between-erdas-and-envi       it has been a while since I last use ENVI ..

Comment: The rrd files are "reduced resolution" overview or pyramid files, not the actual data.

Comment: For reference [Reduced resolution dataset files (RRD)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/reduced-resolution-dataset-files.htm)

Answer (score 2):

ENVI has a data type support page and doesn't list RRD as a supported data layer. [Supported File Types](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/SupportedFormats.html)

Perhaps you can use a file that is a supported data layer to be able to open in ENVI 5.3, as per the comments .img or .tif

Comment: Do you have an idea of ​​how to convert them?

Comment: Don't you have the full resolution data available? Rrd files are subsampled versions from the native data and not really meant to be used alone. Native data are for example as .img or .tif.